# Solving for $x$ in an equation involving rational powers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$128000-256x^{3/4}\left(\frac{256}{625x}\right)^{1/4}=0$

I need help doing the problem.

The answer is $625$.

I started off by isolating $128000,$ but now I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, we first add $-256x^{3/4}\left( \frac{256}{625x}\right)^{1/4}$ to both sides to give us $256x^{3/4}\left( \frac{256}{625x}\right)^{1/4}=128000$.

You have a property that says that $(xy)^r=x^ry^r$ and that $(x/y)^r=x^r/y^r$.  How can this simplify the expression on the left?

Comment: 4/5x ? is that right?

Comment: Well, the $(256/625x)^{1/4}$ bit, using the identities I gave above, gives us $(256)^{1/4}/(625)^{1/4}x^{1/4}=4/5x^{1/4}$, so you were on the right track, but forgot to raise $x$ to the $1/4$.  Recall that $1/x^r=x^{-r}$ and $x^ax^b=x^{a+b}$.  Then we have $4(256)x^{3/4}/x^{1/4}=128000$.  Using the above identities should be able to simplify this down for you.

Comment: 1024x^3/4)/x^(1/4)

Comment: ok hayden i think i got it from now the properties helped thanks!